# Apache CXF support in WSO2 ESB for creating the proxy services

Tags: wso2-esb

Can we create the proxy service using Apache CXF engine in wso2ESB?

Answer (score 0):

no. ESB proxy service is always an AxisService. Most of the ESB/Synapse transports are also axis2 dependant.